# How to put user id in registered claims

Tags: c#, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

[image]I am using asp.net core web api this is a piece of code, where i am using registered claims to add username and email in jwt token payload, now the question is.[image]
How can I send user id in registered claims like username and email.
on line number 45 (if you see code image)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCm42.png)

```
if (userdata!=null)
            {
                var secretkey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("secret key here");
                var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(secretkey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
                var claims = new[] {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Name,userdata.Username),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email,userdata.Email),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.,userdata.Id),
                };
```

Comment: What language and library is this? Neither of the tags you've added to your question seem to be relevant, so users who can help you won't spot the question. Please also include the full details of any error your getting, as text not an image, as currently it's not clear what your question actually is.

Comment: Hi @Patrick, `JwtRegisteredClaimNames.` You miss the property in this struct. Or you can just use simple string `new Claim("Id",userdata.Id),`

Comment: Hi @Patrick, how do you know there is no id in claims, pls share the code.

Comment: Hi @Rena thank you for your message but i already tried this, there is no id in jwt registered claim names.  so i can used jti or sid like this new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti,userdata.Id.ToString()),

Comment: @rena you can see the list of registered claims

Answer (score 2):

Usually, the user ID is added as the `sub` claim, which stands for "subject". It identifies the subject of the token, in your case, the user. Usually, it contains the user ID, email, or login.

So, in your case:

```
new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, userdata.Id),
```

Still, I'm pretty sure you are able to use any string as the claim name. Tokens don't have to consist only of registered claims. They can contain any claims. Something like this should also work:

```
new Claim("my_own_user_id_claim", userdata.Id),
```